# ggvis, error in function( ) : attempt to apply non-function : post sessionInfo()

Tags: r

```
library("dplyr") 
library("ggvis")
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt,~mpg) %>% layer_points()
sessionInfo()
```

I posted sessionInfo() because I have an Error in (function ()  : attempt to apply non-function. 
When I use R markdown and run, it works. It has error all the time, when I run it in R.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Try restarting your session and running those lines again. If the problem still occurs, post the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue to this.

I updated Rstudio from ver  0.98.1102 to ver  0.98.1103 and it's working now

Test to see if you can get ggvis to work in vanilla R to see if it's Rstudio behind your problem

Good Luck